# Why is zsh not executing my regular expression correctly?

Tags: regex, zsh

I started using [zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) a while back (installed using brew as [described here](https://gist.github.com/derhuerst/12a1558a4b408b3b2b6e)).

Everything's working great but I've noticed that the regular expression operator `=~` doesn't really work.

---

For example if I want to extract the file name of a JSON file from a path I get the correct result in bash but not in zsh.

I.e.

```sh
bash -s 
[[ "/a/b/c/file.json" =~ ([[:alnum:]\-]+)\.json$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

works and yields `file` but the same thing in zsh just prints an empty line.

---

Does anyone know why and how to fix this? Do I have to enable regex support somehow?

Comment: Did you enable the relevant option?

Comment: @melpomene Which one is the relevant option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, found it. The [zsh docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html) clarify that matches are stored in the variable `match` rather than `BASH_REMATCH` as in Bash.

So, obtaining the match like this

```sh
[[ "/a/b/c/file.json" =~ ([[:alnum:]\-]+)\.json$ ]] && echo ${match[1]}
```

works as expected.